# Recursive function for digit sum in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-c++

Tried writing a recursive function for digit sum in c++ ; ended up getting the last digit instead. Can anyone suggest fixes..
'''

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int dsum (int n, int sum)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        sum = sum + (n%10);
        n = n/10;
        return(n ,sum);
    }
    else return sum;

}

int main()
{
    int i = 345;
    int s = dsum (i,0);
    cout<<"Sum is "<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: There is no recursion. `return (n,sum)` -> `return dsum(n,sum)`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: pay attention to warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/b6sxjhzMK. For comma operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call the recursion as seen in here:

```cpp
int dsum (int n, int sum)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        sum = sum + (n%10);
        n = n/10;
        return(n ,sum); // <-- this line
    }
    else return sum;

}
```

Notice you `return(n ,sum);` instead of `return dsum(n ,sum);`. `return(n ,sum);` fist evaluates the left operand: `n` and then the right operand: `sum`. Since there's nothing to evaluates, it will returns the result of the right operand, which is `sum`.

Comment: What do you mean by " Since there's nothing to evaluates"?

Comment: @Bathsheba I mean that there’s no change to n and sum